# Sql to get all records from yesterday's turn

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I need a SQL condition to get rows from a table that were created between 6:00 a.m yesterday and 7:00 a.m today. The table has a `creationDate` field.

This is the approach I was thinking of

```
select *
from myTable   
where creationDate = DATE_SUB(CONCAT(CURDATE()), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

I'm using mysql server 5. Also my time is not on the creationDate field, it's on a separated field called startTime.

Comment: Please tell us which database you are using.

Comment: i was trying something like this: creationDate = DATE_SUB(CONCAT(CURDATE(), \' 00:00:00\'),
INTERVAL 1 DAY)

Comment: I'm using mysql server 5

Comment: sorry for the delay i was very busy today and could respond earlier... I've left a comment on your reply. thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tested and it works (this assumes that your creationDate column is of type timestamp):

```
select * from mytable
where
creationDate between concat(date(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day)), ' 06:00:00') and concat(date(now()), ' 07:00:00')
```

Note the whitespace in front of the time value, i.e. ' 06:00:00'

EDIT cause of further specification in comment:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE
(creationDate >= date(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day)) AND creationTime >= '06:00:00')
AND
(creationDate <= date(now()) AND creationTime <= '07:00:00')
```

Yes, it needs to be this clumsy now, because if you would simply write something like (pseudocode)

```
...WHERE creationDate between today and yesterday AND creationTime between '06:00:00' and '07:00:00'
```

you would get the timespan of 1 hour for today and yesterday.

Comment: okay this looks nice enough and i think it could work, but i have my time field in a separated field called startTime... could you modify your answer to adjust to that ? thanks...

Answer (score 0):

try to do this:

```
select *
from myTable   
where creationDate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 25 HOUR);
```

Comment: this would return the whole day... as i stated in my question i need from 6:00 a.m yesterday to 7:00a.m today

Comment: i think the problem here is that this is a table that generates records every minute. if i don't define 6:00 a.m as it's start point i would return records i don't need for this report. thanks for the help.

Comment: @RichardGonzálezAlberto so work on hour interval, is my edit helps you?

Comment: it could work... but it would depende on the execution time... i need something that explicits declare a time range...

Comment: @RichardGonzálezAlberto 25 HOUR is a time range

Comment: yes... but if i were to execute this query at 22:00 hours instead of 07:00 hours, it wouldn't return the records that i needed. Also my creationDate doesn't contain the time, it's on different field called startTime.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select *
from myTable   
where creationDate >= 
DATE_SUB(concat(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), %Y-%m-%d), ' 07:00:00'), INTERVAL 25 HOUR)
AND
creationDate <= concat(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), %Y-%m-%d), ' 07:00:00')
```

Comment: thanks... what if i have my time in a separated field called start time?

Comment: What do you want to replace creationDate or instead of NOW() do you want StartDate? if u want startDate instead of NOW() replace it with startDate in above query.